# Не могу понять как вернуть несколько строк в конструкции switch-case

Tags: c#

Есть задача:

> Если ввод 'H', верните 'Hello World!'
>   Если вход есть 'Q', верните вход.
>   Если ввод '9', верните полный текст 99 бутылок пива. Это должно быть отформатировано так:
>
> 99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
>
> Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.
>
> 98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer.
>
> Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall.
>
> 97 bottles of beer on the wall, 97 bottles of beer.
>
> Take one down and pass it around, 96 bottles of beer on the wall.

Мой код:

```
public static string Interpret(string code)
{
    switch(code)
    {
      case "H":
        return "Hello World!";
      break;

      case "Q":
      return code;


      case "9":
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
      return $"{i} bottles of beer on the wall\n{i} bottles of beer\nTake one down, pass it around\n{1} bottles of beer on the wall\n""
      }
      default:
      return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cформируйте результирующий массив строк (сконкатенируйте строки) в цикле, и уже за его пределами возвращайте. Пример:

```
case "9":
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
   sb.Append(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall\nblah-blah", i));
  }
return sb.ToString();
```

Ваш код выходит из цикла на первой итерации по оператору return.

### Update

Реализация по условию задачи:

```
    case "9":
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; --i)
    {
       sb.Append(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {1} bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, {2} bottles of beer on the wall.\n", i, i, i - 1));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Цикл в обратную сторону должен быть по условию задачи

Comment: @yolosora добавил реализацию, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: А почему string.Format вместо интерполяции?

Comment: @PavelMayorov из-за версии языка :)